# Generic function using an ordereddictionary within an object

Tags: c#

I have a List of objects of type "MyObject". This class contains an orderedDictionary. I want to use is orderedDictionary in a generic function

```
public class MyObject
{
    public OrderedDictionary Columns { get; set; }
}
```

My generic function

```
    private void KeepSelectedColumns<T>(List<T> OperateList)
    {
        List<string> ToBeRemoved = new List<string>();
        foreach (T fVal in OperateList)
        {
            // error in fVal.Columns
            foreach (DictionaryEntry Col in fVal.Columns)
            {
                 ...
                 ...
            }
        }
    }
```

The complier error is 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Columns' and no extension method 'Columns' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why do you need a generic function if you have `List<MyObject>` as you said? Or does your list store some other types inherited from `MyObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you provide no restrictions on the Type of `T`, it can be "anything" - but not everything you *could* pass in as the type parameter `T` has a member property called `Columns`, so the compiler complains.

For example, you could pass in a `List<int>`, as that would satisfy the parameter, but `int` doesn't have a `Columns` member.

Are you sure you want generics here? Unless you use `MyObject` as a base class to other classes, you're wanting behaviour that's explicitly "not generic" - it's too specific.

If `MyObject` is a base class, you could use generics but would need to provide more type constraints - your function signature would look like:

```
private void KeepSelectedColumns<T>(List<T> OperateList) where T : MyObject
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more information on type constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this with types that derivatives from yours MyObject add where constrain like this

```
private void KeepSelectedColumns<T>(List<T> OperateList) where T : MyObject
{
        List<string> ToBeRemoved = new List<string>();
        foreach (T fVal in OperateList)
        {
            // error in fVal.Columns
            foreach (DictionaryEntry Col in fVal.Columns)
            {
            }
        }
}
```